# меню в вордпресс

Tags: wordpress

как сделать чтоб кликая на ссылку в меню ,сайт опускался к тому разделу. движок вордпресс , плагин Themify

[image: скриншот сайта]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Разделу присваиваете `id`, например `block_1`
2. В меню прописываете произвольную ссылку вида `#block_1`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]